# pyinstaller 3.2 failed to execute script

Tags: exe, pyinstaller

I am having a problem with pyinstaller 3.2 and wonder if someone can help me. I have a simple script shown below.

```
import subprocess
import os

path_to_pdf = os.path.abspath('D:\Hello.pdf')
path_to_acrobat = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat Reader DC\Reader\AcroRd32.exe'

process = subprocess.Popen([path_to_acrobat, '/A', 'search=hello, path_to_pdf], shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
process.wait()
```

When I compile this into an exe using pyinstaller and the option --debug it works fine but has the cmd window that I don't want. However, when I repeat the process but use the option --windowed I get the error message "failed to execute script". Any ideas how to get around this problem would be very gratefully accepted

Answer (score 0):

Stumbled across the answer.

Its all because of "stdout". On another query it states it has a buffer size and if things don't fit it wont work. All I had to do was take this out and its works fine.